# Correct way to use logical operators

Tags: php

I've got this bit of code and I want to modify it:

```
if ( ! empty( $_GET[ 'taxonomy' ] ) && $_GET[ 'taxonomy' ] == 'custom1' || 'custom2' && $pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' )
```

Yes, it's a Wordpress statement, but the issue is the PHP || operator. I want the $_GET[ 'taxonomy'] to equal either custom1 or custom2.

Is the following the proper way to code this?

```
if ( ! empty( $_GET[ 'taxonomy' ] ) && $_GET[ 'taxonomy' ] == ('custom1' || 'custom2') && $pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' )
```

Comment: *Is the following the proper way to code this?* Short and simple: Nope. The correct way would be: `if ( ! empty( $_GET[ 'taxonomy' ] ) && $_GET[ 'taxonomy' ] == "custom1" || $_GET[ 'taxonomy' ] ==  "custom2" && $pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' )`

Comment: `if ( ! empty( $_GET[ 'taxonomy' ] ) && ($_GET[ 'taxonomy' ] == 'custom1' || $_GET[ 'taxonomy' ] ==  'custom2') && $pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
if ( isset($_GET['taxonomy']) && ($_GET['taxonomy'] == 'custom1' || $_GET['taxonomy'] == 'custom2') && $pagenow == 'edit-tags.php')
```

Comment: And why does OP has to do it this way: `($_GET['taxonomy'] == 'custom1' || $_GET['taxonomy'] == 'custom2')` and can't do it this way: `$_GET[ 'taxonomy' ] == ('custom1' || 'custom2')` ?

Comment: What does OP mean?    And, the parentheses make more sense to me, if you compare it to algebra.    The parentheses didn't work. I don't know why.